# anchor do nothing after second index

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I have a django-qcm with sections that change when clicking on anchors and using the scroll snap type property.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        html{
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
          }
        body{
            background-color: #72a9d6;
            color: white;
            font-family: "Mont", sans-serif;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        section{
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 100vh;
            /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
            scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
            scroll-behavior: smooth; 
        }
        .container{ 
            padding: 5%;
            display: grid;
            position: relative;
            justify-items: center;
            gap: 3px;
            scroll-snap-align: center;
            height: 100%;  
        }
        .question_title{
            height: 50px;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: 500;
            text-align: center;
            
        }
        .space_title{
            height: 150px;
        }
        .container_reps{
            max-width: 30%;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            column-count:2;
            height: 20%;   
        }
        .rep{
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            border:1px solid white;
            padding: 0 5px ;
            max-width: 15%;
            min-width: 250px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            max-height: 40px;
        }
        .rep:hover{
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        }
        .dot_rep{
            background-color: #63c7f5;
            border: 1px solid white;
            color: white;
            margin-right: 7px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .text_rep{
            font-weight: 700;
        }
        .check{
           margin-left: 40%;
        }
        </style>
        
        
        <section>
               
            <div id="1" class="container">
                <div class="question_title">
                    <div class="space_title"></div>
                    <p>Question 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="container_reps">
                    <div class="rep">
                        <span class="dot_rep">1</span><p class="text_rep">rep 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rep">
                        <span class="dot_rep">1</span><p class="text_rep"> rep 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rep">
                        <span class="dot_rep">1</span><p class="text_rep">rep3</p>
                    </div>               
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div id="2" class="container">
                <div class="question_title">
                    <div class="space_title"></div>
                    <p>Question 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="container_reps">
                    <div class="rep">
                        <span class="dot_rep">1</span><p class="text_rep">rep 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rep">
                        <span class="dot_rep">1</span><p class="text_rep"> rep 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rep">
                        <span class="dot_rep">1</span><p class="text_rep">rep3</p>
                    </div>              
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div id="3" class="container">
                <div class="question_title">
                    <div class="space_title"></div>
                    <p>Question 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="container_reps">
                    <div class="rep">
                        <span class="dot_rep">1</span><p class="text_rep">rep 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rep">
                        <span class="dot_rep">1</span><p class="text_rep"> rep 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rep">
                        <span class="dot_rep">1</span><p class="text_rep">rep3</p>
                    </div>               
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="4" class="container">
                <div class="question_title">
                    <div class="space_title"></div>
                    <p>Question 4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="container_reps">
                    
                    <div class="rep">
                        <span class="dot_rep">1</span><p class="text_rep">rep 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rep">
                        <span class="dot_rep">1</span><p class="text_rep"> rep 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rep">
                        <span class="dot_rep">1</span><p class="text_rep">rep3</p>
                    </div>               
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </section>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
             function scrollToAnchor(ind){
        
        const aTag = $("#"+ind);
        $('body,section').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
    }

    //scrollToAnchor('2');

    var container_page = document.getElementsByClassName('container')
    

    const reps = document.getElementsByClassName('rep');
    [].forEach.call(reps,function(rep){
        $(rep).click(function(){
            if(! rep.querySelector('.check')){
                [].forEach.call(reps,function(repToDel){
                    if(repToDel.querySelector('.check')){
                        repToDel.querySelector('.check').remove()
                        $(repToDel).css("border", "1px solid white")
                    }
                })
                $(rep).last().append('<div class="check"><object data="{% static "img/Coin-Magpharm-V3.png" %}" width="20" > </object></div>');
                $(rep).css("border", "2.5px solid white");

               
                    let x = parseInt($(rep).closest('.container').attr('id'))
                    //var y = x.toString()
                    console.log(x)
                    scrollToAnchor(x+1) 
               
                
                

                 
            }
            
        })
    })

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first anchor works fine, but after the second nothing happens. The function scrollToAnchor(3) works fine when called in the console.
I tried to change different dom parameters to reach the container id and the int and str but nothing changes except errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with this code:

```
var container_page = document.getElementsByClassName('container')
 
const reps = document.getElementsByClassName('rep');
[].forEach.call(reps, function(rep) {
  $(rep).click(function() {
    if (!rep.querySelector('.check')) {
      [].forEach.call(reps, function(repToDel) {
        if (repToDel.querySelector('.check')) {
          repToDel.querySelector('.check').remove()
          $(repToDel).css("border", "1px solid white")
        }
      })
      $(rep).last().append('<div class="check"><object data="{% static "img/Coin-Magpharm-V3.png" %}" width="20" > </object></div>');
      $(rep).css("border", "2.5px solid white");

      var x = parseInt($(rep).closest('.container').attr('id'));
      document.getElementById((++x).toString()).scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth' 
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you're getting the `.container` id, instead you might use the number of the clicked `.rep`.

Try something like this:

```js
let x = parseInt($(rep).index()) + 1
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, the counting is good, but there is a problem with the third question !!!! 
check this codelab if you would run it : https://codepen.io/abdoutech93/pen/XWBaeGX?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean up your JS, in the link below you can find a solution with js and css with the same need, instagram stroies clone component. check this [tutorial](https://web.dev/codelab-building-a-stories-component/) entire solution, well coded.